# How to float elements beyond modal container using nyromodal

Tags: javascript, html, nyromodal

I regularly employ elements and images that are floated beyond the boundaries of their containers - it adds dimension, assists with spacing and adds a bit of flair.

In this instance I am using NyroModal v2 to load html (a div tag containing various other elements) into a modal window. I had planned an image element (within the modal) would be floated just a bit outside the boundaries of the nyromodal but the modal dialog is clipping the element that goes beyond the modal's boundaries despite position absoloute or relative and regardless of very high z-index.

Looking for suggestions... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok a bit more digging using chrome debugger: the nyromodal container has a computed style added to it within the _reposition function:

```
this.elts.cont.css('overflow', 'auto');
```

I commented it out and my elements float beyond the border but this is not a solution if your modal content needs scrolling - it will need to fit within the screen or you will likely have unpredictable and unsatisfactory results.

There is another function (hideCont) which sets the nyromodal container overflow to hidden when you close the modal:

```
nm.elts.cont.css('overflow', 'hidden').fadeOut(clb);
```

I changed 'hidden' to '' and I have the desired behavior.

NyroModal is on github and perhaps a fork that adds this functionality (without breaking scrolling content) would be useful - I don't have the time so above is my solution - it works for me in this instance and hopefully may be a satisfactory quick-fix for others.